# Whats the datatype of a Glade file?

Tags: gtkmm, gtk3

following the official tutorial of gtkmm 3, this is how to instantiate a glade file:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder=Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("basic.glade");
```

So, what's the datatype for "basic.glade"? I know its XML but how to do that in code?

In GTK 2.4 it was:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gnome::Glade::Xml> &refXml;
```

This does not work for me in gtkmm 3 / GTK 3 any more. What I want is to create a class and I need to declare the correct datatype.

Thanks

P.S
The tutorial I am going through is [this](http://www.c-plusplus.de/forum/113239). I know the code is 2.x, I want to do the same in 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gtk::Builder` is the replacement for `Gnome::Glade::Xml`.